# Does Increasing Insulation Thickness from 20cm to 35cm of Glass Wool Really Make a Difference in Insulation Quality?

Tags: insulation

A professional came today to inspect the mechanical ventilation system. They found that the insulation level in the attic is insufficient (less than 20cm of glass wool).

They strongly recommended adding more insulation (an additional layer of mineral wool to reach approximately 35cm).

Can adding a new layer to reach 35cm really improve the insulation quality of the house, considering the significant cost of the service?

Comment: The attic is one of the big heat lost areas.  Why worry about the significant cost of service, buy the insulation and place it yourself.  You just need gloves and a mask, maybe a sharp knife and save on fuel cost.

Comment: didnt think about this, well I think it's very easy to do it myself 
but it didint answer my original question "can this increase insulation?"
https://www.leroymerlin.fr/produits/materiaux/isolation/laine-de-verre/laine-de-verre-plafond/laine-de-verre-a-souffler-knauf-insulation-16-6kg-r-variable-selon-epaisseur-69570270.html

Answer (score 1):

The cost has nothing to do with the improvement in insulation, and as @crip659 notes, you can **drastically reduce** the cost by Doing It Yourself. Or shopping around for other quotes to have it done if that's not an option for you.

Yes, nearly doubling the attic insulation depth will absolutely help. I have nearly 50cm of attic insulation, personally, but I don't know your climate. Attic insulation is often inadequate, particularly in older houses, and the easiest place to add more, normally.

Also, if your current insulation leaves ceiling framing exposed, wood has a much lower R-value than insulation, so a layer covering the old insulation **and the framing** will make a larger difference than you might think if you assume that insulation value = the value of the insulation and ignore the additional loss through the wood framing members every 12, 16 or 24 inches.

The difference in heating/cooling energy use **from the current use** is exactly proportional to the difference in effective insulation value. If you double the insulation value, you halve your current energy use for heating or cooling. The claim made in another answer of "a 1% difference" is from a state where the building was at R=1 (which few buildings that are completely uninsulated even hit, as wood and wall material have some inherent insulation value) NOT from the present state of insulation (which is unknown, as you say "less than 20cm", but not how much.)

Answer (score 1):

R-value is related to the thickness of the insulation. Assuming you current insulation of 20cm (8 inches) [has R-value of 28](https://learnmetrics.com/insulation-r-value-chart-per-inch/) after adding extra insulation to 35cm (14 inches) will raise tour R-value to 51.

Now, I am a bit fuzzy on that one, but I heard that [R-value of 28 means that it passes 1/28 part of heat](https://natureofhome.com/what-is-r-value-for-insulation/) or ~3%. R-value of 51 will pass 2% of heat through.

Now, you have to decide for yourself whether difference of 1%% is worth the cost. Notice that while you get 75% increase in insulation, in real terms it might not be noticeable. That is what "diminishing returns" mean.

Regarding cost: the contractors are buying insulation in much larger volumes than individuals. That is why your [local store will happily](https://www.garagejournal.com/forum/threads/insulation-prices.482583/) sell you insulation at the same $ amount as contractor will purchase & install it. So while for smaller jobs it might make sense to DIY, for larger projects contractors can give you a better deal.

Comment: Question states "less than 20 cm" **not** 20 cm existing.

Comment: The R value is not the inverse of the fraction of heat it lets through, and the link you included doesn't make that claim.  Doubling the R value will cut the heat loss in half.  The roof is generally the largest area of heat loss, and the easiest/cheapest place to add insulation.  Increasing the attic insulation from 20 to 35 cm is almost certainly the single most effective step to reduce heat loss.

Answer (score 0):

When we designed our house with passive solar gains taken into account,  we put 20cm of insulation under the concrete slab for the floor, 30cm in all the outer walls and 40cm in the roof with 10cm of that being sheep's wool.

The heat loss or gain of that building was designed to match with the solar water heating input to the underfloor heating and that would be topped up by the woodstove for about 10 weeks of the year depending on the cloud cover.

The building is still outperforming houses built more recently as they don't want to match the efforts we went to.